# Facing issue with HttpClient timeout when reference is added to StackExchange.Redis in the project

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis, .net-4.8

We are facing a weird issue where adding StackExchange.Redis nuget package reference results into issues with System.Net.Http nuget. The issues are resulting into timeouts when client.SendAsync is called.
After removing the reference of StackExchange.Redis , everything works fine with HttpClient class in System.Net.Http.
The projects are all targeted for .Net framework 4.8.
Can someone please help?